# Calling a function as a variable

Tags: javascript, function

I've been going at a small snippet of code for like an hour or two now, but can't seem to figure out why my Javascript breaks down at the end of this code.

```
// Getting username from address bar and user ID from username
var siteHref = window.location.href;
var specifiedUser = siteHref.split('#');
var userName = specifiedUser[1];
var userURL = 'http://soundcloud.com/' + userName;

var idGetter = SC.get('/resolve', { url: userURL }, function(user) {
     SC.get('/users/', function() {

     var userInfo = new Array(3);
        userInfo[0] = user.username;
        userInfo[1] = user.id;
        userInfo[2] = user.public_favorites_count;

        console.log(userInfo);
        console.log(userInfo[2]);

    });
});
```

I've added the variables at the top for a bit of context. To explain this function passes the two parts of the array that I've specified into the console, which is perfect. Only when I call the variable is shows up as undefined?

I also tried wrapping this in an additional function and has no luck calling it.

Anyone have idea where I've gone wrong?

Comment: "Only when I call the variable is shows up as undefined?" Can you elaborate? What variable is `undefined`? And when are you checking it?

Comment: Where in your code are you getting undefined?

Comment: Right after the two values are logged into the console. I call idGetter and get an error saying idGetter is not defined. Wouldn't idGetter just re-run the function and give those two values again?

Comment: @jermainecraig Could you add this line of code in to your example for clarity?

Comment: This particular code runs fine, but I can't call the variable idGetter in order to re-run the code.

Comment: `idGetter` isn't a function, it's a variable that contains whatever `SC.get()` returned.

Comment: @jermainecraig `SC.get()` likely doesn't `return` anything, defaulting to `undefined`, which is what's being assigned to `idGetter`.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski In the console SC.get returns "jermainecraig" which is user.username and the other array.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski Ahhh, this is making much more sense. Thanks I'll give it another look based on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`idGetter` isn't a function, you can't call it. If you want it to be a function, write:

```
var idGetter = function () {
    SC.get('/resolve', { url: userURL }, function(user) {
        SC.get('/users/', function() {

            var userInfo = new Array(3);
            userInfo[0] = user.username;
            userInfo[1] = user.id;
            userInfo[2] = user.public_favorites_count;

            console.log(userInfo);
            console.log(userInfo[2]);

        });
    });
};
```

Then you can do `idGetter()` to run the function.

Comment: I think the problem may lie outside of this snippet of code, as I tried this but it's returning the function to the console, and not the actual output of the function? Is this what I should be expecting. Sorry total newbie.

Comment: Okay, thing is idGetter(); as a function call returns exactly what I need, but idGetter as a variable call doesn't, am I to expect this?

Comment: Of what use is this solution?  All  it does is wrap this in yet another function which doesn't solve any particular problem - it just creates a new outer function.  I don't understand what problem this solves or perhaps what problem the OP was actually having.

Comment: @jermainecraig If `SC.get` returns a function, then assigning it to `idGetter` makes it a function, so you need to call it as a function.

Comment: @jermainecraig It would probably help if we knew what `SC.get` was. Is this part of some 3rd-party library?

Answer (score 2):

You are calling two asynchronous functions.  The results you get in the second one are ONLY valid inside that callback function or in a function you call from there.  You can't use them globally afterwards because the async functions have not yet finished yet and thus they are still `undefined`.

Plus, if you're asking about the `userInfo` variable, that goes out of scope as soon as the callback returns so it is not available anywhere else.

See the comments I added to your code:

```
// Getting username from address bar and user ID from username
  var siteHref = window.location.href;
  var specifiedUser = siteHref.split('#');
  var userName = specifiedUser[1];
  var userURL = 'http://soundcloud.com/' + userName;

  var idGetter = SC.get('/resolve', { url: userURL }, function(user) {
      SC.get('/users/', function() {

       var userInfo = new Array(3);
          userInfo[0] = user.username;
          userInfo[1] = user.id;
          userInfo[2] = user.public_favorites_count;

          console.log(userInfo);
          console.log(userInfo[2]);

          // ** you must use userInfo here or call some other function
          // ** and pass userInfo to it

      });
  });

  // ** you cannot use userInfo here as it is both out of scope and
  // ** has not yet been set
```

The `idGetter` value will contain whatever the first call to `SC.get()` returns which will NOT be the eventual asynchronous result.  If you tell us what `SC.get()` is, then we might be able to help you understand what it returns.

If `SC.get()` is the SoundCloud function, then it appears that it returns nothing and thus that is why `idGetter` is `undefined`.

FYI, I confirmed [here in the SoundCloud source](https://github.com/soundcloud/soundcloud-javascript/blob/master/src/sc/api.coffee#L56) that `SC.get()` does not return anything.

---

If all you're trying to do is to create a new function that contains all this code and will call a callback when the results are available, you can just define that function and then call it:

```
function getUserInfo(callback) {

    // Getting username from address bar and user ID from username
      var siteHref = window.location.href;
      var specifiedUser = siteHref.split('#');
      var userName = specifiedUser[1];
      var userURL = 'http://soundcloud.com/' + userName;

      SC.get('/resolve', { url: userURL }, function(user) {
          SC.get('/users/', function() {

           var userInfo = new Array(3);
              userInfo[0] = user.username;
              userInfo[1] = user.id;
              userInfo[2] = user.public_favorites_count;

              console.log(userInfo);
              console.log(userInfo[2]);

              // ** you must use userInfo here or call some other function
              // ** and pass userInfo to it
              callback(userInfo);

          });
      });

      // ** you cannot use userInfo here as it is both out of scope and
      // ** has not yet been set
}

// then, you can call it like this:
getUserInfo(function(userData) {
    // you can use userData here
});
```

Comment: I'm actually not trying to call userInfo, but rather idGetter.

Comment: @jermainecraig - idGetter contains whatever your first `SC.get()` call returns which will NOT be the asynchronous result that is eventually collected.  If you tell us what `SC.get()` is, then we could perhaps help you understand what it returns.

Comment: @jermainecraig - see the info I added to the end of my answer about `SC.get()`.

Answer (score 0):

I can only assume that `userInfo[2]` is showing as undefined since it would not make since for `userInfo` to be undefined.  If that is the case, then it is probable that `user.public_favorites_count` is undefined.  Trying printing that out to the console, and when it shows up as undefined, you'll need to determine why that is happening.  Without more information about what that object is, or the code returning that object, there's not much more help the community will be able to provide.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to either be working, or is a step forward.

```
var idGetter = function () { SC.get('/resolve', { url: userURL }, function(user) {
      SC.get('/users/', function() {

       var userInfo = new Array(3);
          userInfo[0] = user.username;
          userInfo[1] = user.id;
          userInfo[2] = user.public_favorites_count;

          console.log(userInfo);
          console.log(userInfo[2]);

      });
  });
};

var idGetter = idGetter();
```

Setting the variable before the function, and re-setting it after. Not sure if this is standard practise, but seems to work to some extent.